# How to do a Proof by induction.If $X_1,X_2,...,X_n $ are independent random variables. Then $a_1X_1+b_1,a_2X2+b_2,...,a_nX_n+b_n$ are independent.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $X_1,X_2,...,X_n $ are independent random variables. Then $a_1X_1+b_1,a_2X_2+b_2,...,a_nX_n+b_n$ are independent. Where $a_1,..,a_n,b_1,...,b_n$ are constants.

How to proof by induction. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are plenty of places online where you can find out what mathematical induction is if you just google it.

Comment: Before we get distracted by "induction", let's first make sure we know the definition of *independent random variables*.

Answer (score 1):

First, we prove it true in the case of two variables.

Let $X_1,X_2$ be independent random variables. We wish to show $a_1X_1+b_1$ and $a_2X_2+b_2$ are independent. Recall $X,Y$ are independent iff $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$.

So what is $E((a_1X_1+b_1)(a_2X_2+b_2))$? Well:

$$E((a_1X_1+b_1)(a_2X_2+b_2))=E(a_1a_2X_1X_2+a_1b_2X_1+a_2b_1X_2+b_1b_2)$$

but the expectation function is linear, so we can apply the various friendly and familiar properties of linear functions:

$$E(a_1a_2X_1X_2+a_1b_2X_1+a_2b_1X_2+b_1b_2)$$
$$=E(a_1a_2X_1X_2)+E(a_1b_2X_1)+E(a_2b_1X_2)+E(b_1b_2)$$
$$=a_1a_2E(X_1X_2)+a_1b_2E(X_1)+a_2b_1E(X_2)+b_1b_2$$
$$=a_1a_2E(X_1)E(X_2)+a_1b_2E(X_1)+a_2b_1E(X_2)+b_1b_2$$

(That last step follows since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent.) This is our left hand side. Now we consider the right hand side

$$E(a_1X_1+b_1)E(a_2X_2+b_2)=(a_1E(X_1)+b_1)(a_2E(X_2)+b_2)$$
$$=a_1a_2E(X_1)E(X_2)+a_1b_2E(X_1)+a_2b_1E(X_2)+b_1b_2$$

So we have LHS$=$RHS. We have proven it true in the case of two variables.

The final step is showing that if it is true for $n$ then it must be true for $n+1$. So we assume it is true for $n$; that is, we assume independence of $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ implies independence of $\{a_iX_i+b_i\}_{i=0}^n$ i.e.
$$E(\prod_{i=1}^n(a_iX_i+b_i))=\prod_{i=1}^nE(a_iX_i+b_i)$$
and now we have to prove independence of $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{n+1}$ implies independence of $\{a_iX_i+b_i\}_{i=0}^{n+1}$ i.e.
$$E(\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}(a_iX_i+b_i))=\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}E(a_iX_i+b_i)$$
I'm starting to wonder if there's a less tedious way.